# PHP Response to C#

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I am soon looking at coding a C# Application out of my spare time for a friend of mine, this application will essentially be uploading files from the clients computer to a PHP webscript, using the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and its [UploadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx). I am currently planning out exactly how the script will communicate with the server, and then how it will receive a response containing some information regarding the users upload to the server.

Step 1: User will select file(s) to be uploaded, they will then upload them

Step 2: The program will communicate with a PHP script on our server, which will process through the uploads and upload them to the correct folder

Step 3: The PHP server will then simply respond with a string, array or some sort of response which will be relayed back to the program, this will contain important information, such as;

- Username
- A link
- Date/Time on server uploaded
- An error status

I was thinking the best way to do this was via an array of some sort, however I am lost at this point as I have never really delved into this. I have been told that simply outputting a PHP Array will not do the trick, and I will need to use other means such as JSON or XML. Does anyone have any recommendations for how I should handle the returned data, which I will need to use on the software to display a link and other information such as the date & time(which will actually be in timestamp format).

Cheers,

Comment: You should have to post *concise* code that you're working on.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are dealing with cross language communication JSON is indeed the best format.  XML will work equally well, but I find XML a bit too verbose for the sake of simply transfering data.

Simply....

```
 json_encode($array)
```

...your array, and send the data.  You can parse this data in the C# end easily.  JSON is the best format for most scenarios where you want to send data for use in a variety of languages.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely use JSON in the application

Answer (score 2):

Dumping PHP array will not work because PHP has it's own serializer and c# can't (well maybe it can, but it's not practical) read that.

The suggestion to use JSON or XML was correct, these two formats are pretty good for transferring data. I would say stick with JSON, but that's just a personal preference. Both of them are good for the purpose and both XML and JSON have native implementations in both c# and PHP.

Edit:

- [c# json serialiser documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28loband%29.aspx)
- [PHP json serialiser documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

Comment: Thank you, I was after some reassurance on the matter before I got stuck in and coded it. I will take the JSON route since I know it is used a lot for applications like this where data is being relayed to and from a server, its just I have never used it before so I guess its time to read the documentation. Thanks!